# What reasons are there for having comparisons be only of the form <= and >= (and not including =< and =>)?

Tags: java, c++, compiler-errors

In many languages, such as Java and C/C++, comparisons are always done of the form `<=` and `>=`. For example, here is a working sample program:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Get inputs
        int input1 = s.nextInt();
        int input2 = s.nextInt();

        // compare them
        if (input1 >= input2) {
            System.out.println("Input 1 is greater than or equal to input 2");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Input 1 is less than input 2");
        }
    }
}
```

And this compiles and runs correctly. However, if I change the one comparison line to be:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Get inputs
        int input1 = s.nextInt();
        int input2 = s.nextInt();

        // compare them
        if (input1 => input2) { // ------Changed this line------
            System.out.println("Input 1 is greater than or equal to input 2");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Input 1 is less than input 2");
        }
    }
}
```

It produces a compiler error here, as it does in many other languages.

This is most certainly an error generated from the language's grammar. But why would the grammar forbid such a comparison? From a programmer's perspective, it should not matter on which side of the equal sign the comparison operator is used.

Because both of the comparisons that have the operator on the left side of the equals, it makes sense that the syntax parsing is done linearly (either left-to-right, or vice versa). But why would the order matter?

Comment: For those who downvoted this question, please explain why.

Comment: You've simply missed valid syntax?!? That's also cause of those downvotes probably?

Comment: "From a programmer's perspective, it should not matter on which side of the equal sign the comparison operator is used." Yes it should, because there's no reason to complicate a language by allowing both. Indeed, in some languages (e.g. C#) `=>` is a valid construct, but not duplicating an existing operator.

Comment: that's just plain minimalism. why introduce another string representing the same operator, if we already have an operator. Some other languages use these operators for other purposes (`=>` is the lambda-operator in C# for example)

Comment: The same reason you can't use `IF` instead of `if`. It's the grammar of the language.

Comment: I agree that from the programmer's perspective, since the language is borrowing a math construct, if the programmer is thinking in math constructs (which is reasonable) it shouldn't make a difference.  However, the programmer is actually not writing math constructs (even though the language's borrowing of them makes this somewhat confusing).  The developer is writing a programming language construct, which in this case only provides a subset of valid math constructs.

Comment: Just for info: POP-11 uses => as a print arrow, so C# is not the only language out there using => to mean something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because while `=>` is  a valid math comparator, it is not a valid language token.

Compilers are written making a lot of compromises.  Not supporting every combination of the equals and greater than sign is just one of the compromises made to make the language parsing faster.

--- Updated with a few examples of the complexity referred to above ---

With C++, on the surface it looks like this would be an "easy fix"; where the parser would create the same "GreaterThanOrEqual" token for both inputs; however, it's not as easy as it seems, when one can override the behavior of the "GreaterThanOrEqual" token by writing a `operator>=(...)` method.

Should one provide two `operator>=(...)` and `operator=>(...)` overriding methods?  Should some mechanism be required to make them both the same?  If you define one without the other, should the other be "aliased" back to the defined one?  One can easily see how it would add a lot of corner-case complexity.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons that this can occur. (And note this is purely based upon opinion and personal experience. )

A great deal has to do with common practice and ease of reading the code. It also reduces the complexity of compilers as they don't have to check for a bunch of different cases. (If you add that specific case, their are many more possibilities that would need to be accounted for.) This can be problematic for languages like C/C++ where their are hundreds if not thousands of unique compilers. (It can be hard enough to try and keep them all following standard as is, unnecessary complication isn't likely to help.)

Very curious to see what others think on this issue.

EDIT: As others have commented since I typed this answer, it also is used in other languages to symbolize completely different operations.

Answer (score 0):

**Simply, readability across the entirety of the language.**

Imagine a beginner trying to learn, and using `>=` in all his classes. (As it's the standard.)

Then, he goes out into the wild and is confused by the sudden introduction of `=>` (which also kind of looks like an arrow.)

Even worse, imagine a large enterprise-scale project, where half your coders use `>=` and half use `=>`, code would be a giant cluster `$SWEARWORD`.

It's the same reason we don't have `IF, WHEN, ISTRUE, EXECUTEASLONGAS`, etc. We just have `IF`.

Answer (score -1):

There are languages where you can actually define your own "operators". To be more precise, in languages like Java, C/C++ etc these operators are **"built in"**. However in languages like Smalltalk, there is no concept of operators. Everything is an object and its methods. So even operators like you can define your own **"operators"**. Having said that, I have to add that, although you have the liberty to override or add new operators like that, it is highly discouraged in Smalltalk too.